# Rails: Run raw sql query returning extra info and build models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In rails how can I get raw sql results from the database and *then* turn part of them into active record objects.

More specifically, suppose I have a select statement like:  "SELECT comments.*, c1.sort_order, c2.sort_order" and I want to take each row build a Comment object and then run comment.setpath(c1, c2).  I'm sure there is a function that builds objects and does all the conversions but search as I might I can't seem to locate it.

---

Note that there are plenty of questions I've found on this site that explain how I can execute raw sql that returns rows from a model's table and have that automatically turned into act objects or get raw database values. I want to get the raw data, harvest the extra info I need and turn some of my results into activerecord objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("sql here").map do |hash|
  new_info = harvest_info(hash)
  Comment.new(hash.merge(new_info)) if some_requirement?
end
```

Comment: Yes, but I thought doing it that way would mean I didn't get the benefit of the automatic conversions from the database types to the rails types.  I just checked and it seems to work fine.  I'd have preferred it also execute the after_find callbacks but I can work around that and just hack in manual calls.

Comment: `after_find` only fires when `ActiveRecord` finder methods are used. Maybe `after_initialize` is a better callback in your case if you can change it.

Comment: Ohh, good idea.  Thanks!